# Designing Cache Server using LFU to decrease Database Load

Tags: python, algorithm, caching, hashmap

I am trying to design a Cache Server, that will store the Query and Result key for DB Queries, thus putting less load on it.
It might be something like :

```
if Cache.isSet(query):
       return Cache.get(query)
else:
       result = db.run(query)
       Cache.set(query, result)
       return result
```

Properties of Cache I am planning to design:

- Will be a Cache Server, using REST API
- Will use Hashmap to Store in Key-Value form in RAM
- The Hashmap will be backuped (serialization to a file at intervals)

I am trying to make this Cache for an URL Shortener, but want to expand this as a full fledged Cache Server. 
The Issues I am facing are:

- How will I determine the number of Key-Value Pairs to be stored?
- If the value in DB is changed, will I have to remove the Query(Key) that deals with it?

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The developer of Redis have a great writeup on [Random notes on improving the Redis LRU algorithm](http://antirez.com/news/109) that also covers the LFU implementation. The main idea in the LRU algorithm is to tag objects with a timestamp whenever they are accessed. If you run out of memory, pick five random keys and evict the one with the oldest timestamp. This is an [eventual concistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) approach where you will not find the exact best key to evict, but you will make the dataset better and better on a macro level. The main benefit is that each object carries its own state and you don't need to maintain complex priority lists to keep track of what to evict. The document later builds upon the LRU idea but also shows how to convert it into an LFU algorithm without too much more work.

> How will I determine the number of Key-Value Pairs to be stored?

Use as much memory as possible. The best case with infinite RAM is to cache your entire dataset. With restricted RAM you will have to look at your access patterns. Is there a small core of "hot" objects that are requested most of the time? Then make sure as many of those as possible are cached.

One problem I suspect you might run into with an URL shortener is that you will have a very long tail of URLs. That is, old URLs where each URL is accessed very infrequently but the number of these URLs is so large that they *together* make up a large part of the database load. If this is the case you might need to consider a cache that can fit the entire dataset or some way of speeding up the database queries. The long tail is different than hot objects in that long tail objects are accessed so infrequently that they get evicted from the cache between each access. There is no cache eviction algorithm suitable for a long tail; you either cache the entire long tail or you focus on speeding up raw uncached access.

> If the value in DB is changed, will I have to remove the Query(Key) that deals with it?

Yes, or update the cache. If your system logic can accept some lag you can use a time-to-live on your keys. Then you evict keys older than x seconds. Looking back at Redis, they deal with this by looking at the timestamp when you try to read a key. If the time-to-live have expired they delete the key and return a cache miss.

Comment: Also, is it good to use Caching in a Seperate Server as there might be time lag, and indexing can be used in db?